Using Display implementation to print color to terminal only
I'm currently using the colored crate to add color to my Display implementations, like this:
impl Display for HSEnum {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}: {}",
            self.name.yellow(),
            self.value.to_string().bright_blue()
        )
    }
}

This works fine for printing to the console, however I'm planning on also adding support for saving this output to a file, which results in the ANSI color codes appearing inside the file, which looks wrong as the colors aren't handled properly (unless catted out into the terminal). Is there any way I could have colors only work in the terminal, without duplicating any code to account for the terminal and output separately?
